# Floating action button is giving unneeded colored border

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

The `FloatingActionButton` give hilarious pink border although I don't need that the other one is my original picture that I am attaching in with `FloatingActionButton`

[image]

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/screen_logo"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin='5dp'
        android:src="@drawable/add"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your xml layout for floating action button

Comment: attach code with question

Answer (score 1):

change `colorAccent` to blue in `color.xml`

or use `app:backgroundTint`